Spivak's calculus on manifolds Partition of Unity
On Spivak "Calculus on Manifolds" p63 he provides a proof for the existence of a partition of unity but at some point in the proof for the compact case it looks like he already has the desired partition of unity but for some reason that i don't understand decides to multiply by a new function. Theorem 3.11 on p63 says the following: let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $\mathcal{O}$ be an Open cover of $A$. Then there is a collection $\Phi$ of $C^\infty $ functions $\varphi$ defined in an Open set containing $A$, with the following properties:
$(1)$ For each $x\in A$ we have $0\leq \varphi(x)\leq 1$.
$(2)$ For each $x\in A$ there is an Open set $V$ of $x$ such that all but finitely many $\varphi\in \Phi$ are $0$ on $V$.
$(3)$ For each $x\in A$ we have $\sum_{\varphi\in\Phi}\varphi(x)=1$ (which by $(2)$ is a finite sum).
$(4)$ For each $\varphi\in\Phi$ there is an Open set $U$ in $\mathcal{O}$ such that $\varphi=0$ outside some closed set contained in $U$.
Spivak proceeds by first considering the case where $A$ is compact, so it suffices to construct a partition of unity for a finite subcover $U_1,\dots ,U_n$ of $\mathcal{O}$. He uses problem 1.22 in the book to construct inductively compact sets $D_i\subset U_i$ whose interiors cover $A$. Then he uses problem 2.26 to construct non-negative $C^\infty$ functions $\psi_i$ which are positive on $D_i$ and $0$ outside some closed set $F_i\subset U_i$. Then since the interiors of the $D_i$ cover $A$ we can take an Open set $A\subset U\subseteq \bigcup U_i$ so that $\sum_i \psi_i(x)>0$ for all $x\in U$. On $U$, we can define $$\varphi_i(x)=\frac{\psi_i(x)}{\psi_1(x)+\dots+\psi_n(x)}.$$ Now here is the part which i don't understand: Spivak decides to define a $C^\infty$ function $f:U\to [0,1]$ which is $1$ on $A$ and $0$ outside of some closed set $F\subset U$ and he says that $\Phi=\{f\varphi_1,\dots,f\varphi_n\}$ is the desired partition of unity. ¿Why we need the function $f$ to obtain a partition of unity? It seems to me that the functions $\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_n$ already form a partition of unity, since the conditions $(1),(2),(3)$ are trivially satisfied and for the condition $(4)$ we have that for each $\varphi_i$ we can choose the Open set $U_i$ in $\mathcal{O}$, since $\varphi_i=0$ outside $F_i\subset U_i$ by definition. ¿What i am missing?

This post may be helpful.

@K_D I had seen it before posting my question (which ask the same), but the explanation is not clear (and not formal at all). Why do we care of what happens at the boundary of $\mathrm{supp}(\psi_i)$?? And why do we care if $f$ forces everything go to 0 "near" the boundary of $U$?
